# Bridged wireless interface traffic stats: reversed RX/TX

Tags: networking, linux-networking, wifi, openwrt, wireless-bridge

I just noticed something strange while doing some tests on my OpenWRT router: I have a wifi interface bridged to the LAN, I'm testing download and upload traffic monitoring.

I assumed RX stands for received, so download, while TX stands for transmitted so upload, this works when monitoring the LAN interface, but when monitoring the bridged wireless interface it seems to be reversed, I keep on downloading stuff and TX (upload) is roughly always double the RX (download), anyone knows why is this happening?

I'm using OpenWRT (LEDE 17.01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tx and Rx are always from the perspective of a specific port.

"Tx for upload" is true for the WAN side/port, the LAN side/port (wired or wireless) is the reverse - Rx is towards WAN, Tx is towards LAN.